# Is it possible to get the method body (text) of an Action?

Tags: c#, action, anonymous-delegates

I have a circumstance where I have enqueued a number of `Action` objects and I have a threadpool working through each `Action`. However, if the application shuts down before the queue is empty, I would like to log what is remaining in the queue before closing.

Is it possible to get the method body from an `Action` object? I can see the `MethodBody` object from `Action.Method.GetMethodBody()`, but I don't see a way to get this out as a string.

Any thoughts, or am I crazy?

**EDIT:** One more thing; I would like to retain state information as well. That is, I would like to also retain the values of any variables used within the `Action`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're crazy.

The code being executed has been compiled down to IL, and then JIT compiled to machine code. The text of the action is long gone.

You need to not be queuing Action. Instead, create a structure which contains the Action and the method name, and any other information you want to have logged. Make a queue of *those* instead of Action.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you aren't looking for the textual representation, but for a way to load and save expression trees. I did encounter that problem as well, and while I didn't use it yet, this seems promising: [expression tree serialization](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization).

Comment: This works pretty well for lambdas, but it does not retain state.